# Manipulate json object in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: python, json, angularjs

Curretntly I am working in Python and front side  Angularjs. I am getting data in view with JSON object. Now I want to use that JSON object in my ng-repeat.Below is my code:-

is it possible to use like that??

```
{{result['products']}}


    <div ng-repeat="choice in {{result['products']}}" >
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" ng-model="" value="">

      </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible you don't need `{{}}`:

```
function Ctrl() {
    this.obj = {id: 'a', checked :true, result: {0:0,1:1,2:2}}

};
```

Try this:

```
<div ng:controller="Ctrl"> 
   <div ng:repeat="o in obj.result">
       {{o}}
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the `{{ }}` around the object:

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in result.products" >
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: But I think it will work only if I have $scope.result.products in my controller
but {{result['products']}} object is coming from python not from angular controller.I want to use python returned JSON object in my ng-repeat.